# Jenkins version 2.64 compatible with Apache tomcat version 9?

Tags: jenkins, tomcat

I am currently using Jenkins 2.64 and the same has been deployed and used under Webolic server 12.2.1.4.0. I need to deploy Jenkins 2.64 under Apache Tomcat. Which version of Apache Tomcat is compatible with Jenkins version 2.64?

Is Jenkins version 2.64 compatible with Apache tomcat version 9?

Comment: We are (still) running on tomcat 85 (latest version) with latest Jenkins (LTS) version (2.387.1). As far as I am aware tomcat 9 should be compatible as well. However, you should be aware which tomcat version supports which java version, Servlet, JSP, etc which may impact your server/configuration: https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: @Unforgettable631 Thank you. I am planning to use Tomcat 9 + Open JDK 11+ Jenkins 2.64 combination. Will it work?

Comment: It's not quite common to use such an old Jenkins version with tomcat 9 and JDK11. From documentation perspective I quickly do not see any issue. I would recommend to use a newer Jenkins version that officially supports tomcat 9 and jdk 11. Do not use later versions of tomcat (newer versions of the Servlet API are incompatible with Jenkins): 
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/servlet-containers/#tomcat-9
If I was doing this specific setup (with an old Jenkins version) I would test it first on a test-server to be sure there aren't any issues with your usecases.